# how to direct task exception to main thread?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am handling all of my exceptions in Dispatcher.UnhandledException so I tried to direct exceptions coming from Tasks into this event. |I tried to send exception in the main thread.

```
 task.ContinueWith((t) =>
            {
               ....
               if (t.Exception != null)
                    throw t.Exception;

            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

but I can not take this exception in UnhandledException  event , what is wrong with my solution?

**More Info** , the task and continuation is happening in a RealyCommand in WPF app using MVVM Light:
here is my test view model, **ExecuteTestCommand**  is running in UI thread

```
 class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            App.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += Current_DispatcherUnhandledException;
        }

        void Current_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("got it");
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        #region TestCommand
        private RelayCommand _testCommand;
        public RelayCommand TestCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_testCommand == null)
                    _testCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteTestCommand, CanExecuteTestCommand);
                return _testCommand;
            }
        }
        private bool CanExecuteTestCommand()
        {
            return true;
        }
        private void ExecuteTestCommand()
        {
           // throw new Exception();

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {

                }).ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    App.Current.MainWindow.Title = "It is the main UI thread" + (App.Current.Dispatcher.Thread == System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread).ToString();
                    throw new NotImplementedException();

                }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        }
        #endregion
}
```

Comment: TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() will execute in the context of the thread that started the task, which may or may not be the main thread.

Comment: Do you have subscribed for it in the Main thread: currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler); ?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on FromCurrentSynchronizationContext().  When it breaks, use Debug + Windows + Threads to see what thread it runs on.  If that's not the Main thread then it won't work as you hoped.

Comment: I was testing my application then I changed my application with a simpler version still the same problem, FromCurrentSynchronizationContext is on UI thread but something is wrong maybe I am doing something wrong here. I updated my question

Comment: @duDE i used dispatcher unhandeled event 
App.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of the Task Parallel Library includes an exception handler which ensures (in most cases) that unhandled exceptions within a task do not result in the process terminating. This handler means your `UnhandledException` event will never be called.

When you are not using `async`/`await`, handling exceptions within a task is generally handled by the following process:

1. If your task is actually a sub-task of an "enclosing" task, then the "enclosing" task either propagates the exception or handles it directly (by the steps below).
2. If the code needs to handle exceptions, it generally registers a continuation which checks for the antecedent task entering the `Faulted` status, and performs an appropriate action (such as directly reporting the error to a handler of some form).

I developed the [Rackspace Threading Library](https://github.com/rackerlabs/dotnet-threading/releases/latest) specifically for simplifying these scenarios. The [`Select`](http://rackerlabs.github.io/dotnet-threading/docs-latest/html/Overload_Rackspace_Threading_CoreTaskExtensions_Select.htm) and [`Then`](http://rackerlabs.github.io/dotnet-threading/docs-latest/html/Overload_Rackspace_Threading_CoreTaskExtensions_Then.htm) methods include complete handling for canceled and faulted antecedent tasks so you don't have to check the status of the antecedent in every continuation. The `Select` and `Then` methods which include a `supportsErrors` parameter can be used to handle a faulted task (and not propagate the error to the parent). The [`Finally`](http://rackerlabs.github.io/dotnet-threading/docs-latest/html/Overload_Rackspace_Threading_CoreTaskExtensions_Finally.htm) methods can be used to handle a canceled or faulted task while still propagating the error to the parent.

Answer (score 1):

If you can attach a handler to [TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception(v=vs.110).aspx) you'll catch these exceptions too. However, note that this doesn't necessarily run on your main thread.

If you *need* to handle the exception on your main thread you could add code in the handler to marshal to the main thread (and then even re-throw).

Comment: `UnobservedTaskException` runs after grabage collecting `Task` object, so it's possible that you will have to wait for a long time before it fires.

Comment: @ghord - That's a good point. It's really weird in a running app to have error messages reported a considerable time after the event that triggered them. Very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any explanation why this happens?!!! but to solve my problem I used Dispatcher.Invoke

```
 private void ExecuteTestCommand()
        {
           // throw new Exception();

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {

                }).ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                     if (t.Exception != null)
                   {
                       App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                       {
                           throw t.Exception;
                       }));
                       return;
                   }

                }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        }
```